tensorflow 2.16.1 unable to locate tensorflow.keras.losses
I tried to use
from tensorflow.keras.losses import mean_squared_error

mean_squared_error(train_data, preds)

after doing some predictions. But I just get:

ImportError: cannot import name 'mean_squared_error' from 'tensorflow.keras.losses' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/_tf_keras/keras/losses/init.py)

And if I try to use tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error directly I get:

Could not locate function 'mse'. Make sure custom classes are decorated with '@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()'. Full object config: {'module': 'keras.metrics', 'class_name': 'function', 'config': 'mse', 'registered_name': 'mse'}

Seems to be a 2.16.1 issue as it does not occur with 2.13.0. According to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/MSE it's still part of 2.16.1.
PS.: tf.keras.losses.mse yields the same issue
